# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied trying to save an excel file with python

Tags: python, errno

I am trying to write some data and save it in an excel sheet, so I used openpyxl, it worked its way to access the file, write the data, but not saving the file, the problem is that it did save but the terminal threw an error that stopped the program.

Code:

```
self.wb = lw(f'{self.view.path.text()}')
self.ws = self.wb.active
*******writing some data************
self.wb.save(f'{self.view.path.text()}')
```

Error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I tried excuting this command that is supposed to give my program access, but didn't work, or I did it wrong

```
chown admin:admin filename.xlsx
```

Comment: The `f'{...}'` parts are unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to close the excel file if it is opened cause it can't give the program permission while I am using the file